# Will purging GNOME remove gedit?

Tags: debian, gnome, package-management, gedit

If I remove the GNOME desktop environment from my Debian 7 installation, will that also remove additional applications like gedit or will they remain installed and usable?

Comment: 1. You need to ask a question, if you expect answers. 2. Just try it out, apt-get tells you which packages would be removed and asks for confirmation before uninstalling anything. 3. What packages get removed depends on how they were installed, i.e. pulled in as dependency, recommendation or explicitly. Hence you cannot tell for all Debian installations what would happen if you purged Gnome

Comment: I think the question is quite clear

It involves 2 things that I want to remove GNOME, ok, the second thing is if i remove GNOME then many others apps that were installed during setup, THOSE APPS will remain installed on my system or not.

**HOWEVER STILL YOU THINK THAT THIS QUESTION IS NOT CLEAR JUST REMOVE IT**, Thank you

Comment: If you want to clarify your problem, please edit your post instead of adding a comment. Michael did a lot of editing to your post. Does it describe your problem now and does it include the question you wanted to ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say for sure that purging GNOME will remove gedit, but I can say that gedit will run without gnome, so if you want to use it and remove gnome, just remove gnome then re-install gedit.